# Install C Shell in Ubuntu 11.04 Terminal Temporarily

Tags: bash, command-line

One of my friend wants to use C Shell in Ubuntu 11.04 Terminal instead of Bash Shell for sometime, Is there any way to do it without affecting System in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ubuntu has two options, tcsh and csh. tcsh is better c shell then  csh
To install:

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

To run: Open terminal and type

```
tcsh
```

Comment: i get "unable to locate package"

Answer (score 3):

I think installing the desired shell and doing `chsh -s shell` will change the default login shell. If you want to change shell for a particular user do `usermod -s shellpath username`.

Comment: On Unix, users may configure their environment as they wish :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, you do not have either `csh` or `tcsh` installed on the system.  If you do not want to "affect the system", then I suggest to your friend to download the source code and compile it.  Your friend could then install it relative to the home directory instead of to `/usr` or `/usr/local`.